# How can i get Ngrok domain working correctly

Tags: javascript, php, html, node.js, ngrok

[Endpoints screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JoUY5.png)

I've been struggling with getting NGROK domain working. I have managed to do all the necessary set up and even get different tunnels running simultaneously with NSSM and also, I have paid for the business plan. Please someone should help me out on how to set up the domain and get it working. Thanks

authtoken: 1dr***p
region: us
console_ui: true

tunnels:
first:
proto: http
addr: 80
auth: "username:password"

second:
proto: http
addr: 3049
hostname: access-myfiles.pdf.com
inspect: false
auth: "username:password"

Third:
proto: http
addr: 4459
auth: "username:password"

Forth:
proto: http
addr: 9584
auth: "username:password"

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to see what and [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [stack snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do).

Comment: Could you tell us more about what do you mean by "working"?

Comment: @Palo I created a domain in my ngrok but don't know how to connect it, i have tried all code in the Ngrok Documentation.

Comment: And "connect it" means in this case? Can you edit your post and show some code that you think should work and it does not?

Comment: @Palo I have edit my post and attached a screenshot of my "Endpoints"

Comment: Thank you for the update. It is still not very clear what you are trying to achieve. You only wrote: "getting NGROK domain working" and "how to setup the domain and get it working", but that is obviously not enough. We do not know what does it mean "working" for you. You need to tell us what exactly are you trying to achieve, since NGROK can be used in different scenarios.

Comment: My guess would be that you are trying the "Tunnels on custom domains (white label URLs)" as described in the documentation: https://ngrok.com/docs#http-custom-domains. However I am not sure if  you know what you are doing. It seems that for this you would have to have a control over the configuration of your domain access-myfiles.pdf.com, is that right? Is it your domain? Are you able to configure that domain at some external registrar service?

Comment: @Palo
Yes, you are right by saying i want to have control over the configuration of my domain YES.
Yes it my domain, created in the Ngrok endpoint.
No, I must say i don't know how to configure the domain (access-myfiles.pdf.com) at some external registrar service and i really need help on how to do that. Thanks

Comment: Well, the fact that you created the domain in Ngrok endpoint does not mean you own it. The domain pdf.com is owned by PERFECT PRIVACY, LLC, 5335 Gate Parkway care of Network Solutions PO Box 459, Jacksonville, FL 32256, US. If that is not you then you are not doing a right thing. You need to register your own domain. Alternately, you can use the domains provided by ngrok.com.

Comment: @Palo
I understand you. but the ngrok domain keeps changing all the time, i just want to use one specific url that doesn't change time to time

Answer (score 0):

Instead of making a tunnel to a custom domain outside of ngrok.io, you just want to use a custom subdomain name under ngrok.io domain space, see https://ngrok.com/docs#http-subdomain for more instructions. Under a paid plan this address will remain stable and will not change as is the case in the free NGROK accounts.

Alternately, you can buy your own domain at any of the public domain registrars, and then configure it according to the instructions shown in the message that you have uploaded. In that case you can choose any of the free unused domain names (which is not the case with pdf.com, which is already occupied), but you will have to pay for its registration, which is not very much, if you choose a less popular/costly domain name and TLD. There are plenty of companies which will register a domain for you, just search 'domain registration' at your popular search engine.